# How can I store content with Symfony formbuilder with foreach loop?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is my array `$dataRep`:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => Fields {#7051 ▶}
  1 => Fields {#7328 ▶}
  2 => Fields {#7334 ▶}
  3 => Fields {#7340 ▶}
]
```

I like to store data with Symfony formbuilder in the database:

```
$dataEntity= new Data::class();

foreach ($dataRep as $dataField) {
    $dataEntity->setContent("something");
}
$this->em->persist($dataEntity);
$this->em->flush();
```

But only one entry is stored in the database and not as expected 4 entries.

Comment: Isn't `new Data::class()` a syntax error?

Comment: @Darragh Yes, it is.

Comment: @yivi oh sorry, yes, should be new Data();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code into your loop for it to run on each iteration:

```
foreach ($dataRep as $dataField) {
    $dataEntity = new Data();

    $dataEntity->setContent("something");
    $this->em->persist($dataEntity);
}

$this->em->flush();
```

**Note:** You also had a syntax error that I just noticed (`new Data::class()`).

Comment: `$this->em->flush();` can be used once, no?

Answer (score 2):

You are reseting the content on the same data class and then storing it.
Just foreach the whole process:

```
foreach ($dataRep as $dataField) {
    $dataEntity = new Data();
    $dataEntity->setContent("something");
    $this->em->persist($dataEntity);
}
$this->em->flush();
```

Comment: The `flush();` should be after the foreach, to avoid database query for each entity (and make one global query to save all entity at once). Like in @Script47's answer

Comment: @Etshy it's a best practice, I know. I haven't changed it in order to keep my original solution, because he changed it and both were the same. Anyways I've changed it in order to improve the answer despite being 2 times the same answer.

Comment: Didn't see the others answers was edited too, sorry. but I thing it's best to show "best practice" code, even if it's a duplicate, for later visitors on this post. So, thanks for editing your answers.